# Chosing one file from 2 file almost identical using sed command

Tags: bash, sed

This is my firs post and I am a beginner ...
I have an output file(tempfile4) that contains the following strings:

```
230 User xferus logged in.
250 CWD command successful.
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 'file list'.
302105.aa4
302105.aa4.md5
226 Transfer complete.
```

I wand to chose and save in a variable only the 302105.aa4 string using sed command.
I tried this but only give me the second string 302105.aa4.md5:

```
var=`cat tempfile4 | sed -n "/.aa4/p" |awk '{print $NF}'`
```

Can someone help me please?!
Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be sed? You could to that with `var=$(grep -o '.*\.aa4$' tempfile4)`, assuming that you want the whole line and there is only one line ending in `.aa4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ***grep***:

```
var1=$(grep -o -m1 '[[:alnum:]]*\.aa4' tempfile4)
echo "$var1"
302105.aa4
```